# Drawing sphere in canvas in Android?

Tags: android, geometry, android-canvas

How we can draw a sphere on canvas in Android?[`Canvas`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html&ei=ysHMUKv1KMfPrQf22YDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNFWnXH-XblXXqlYJphAN38VISEv_A&sig2=f_PNkb1xjaLcwJbk9IDwyg&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.bmk) does not have any method to do this.

Comment: Draw a circle and give it a gradient texture to have a spherical appearance. If you want an actual 3D representation, use OpenGL.

Comment: @RaghavSood Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a circle and give it a gradient texture to have a spherical appearance. If you want an actual 3D representation, use OpenGL.

As the canvas isn't really meant for 3D space items, it only supports primitives like circles and lines and arcs.

However, OpenGl is a full fledged graphics API which can be used to draw spheres and maintain lighting and textures etc.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is 2d it has draw circle. canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, new Paint())